# Outputting PID of Rails server(s) with ps aux | grep - breaks when put into an alias?

Tags: bash, grep, process

I'm trying to create an alias for an unwieldy command I'm using to output the PID and some other information about two rails servers I have running.

When I simply run the command in terminal (over ssh):

```
vagrant@Railsvr:~$ ps aux | grep rails | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2, $12, $13, $14, $15}'
```

I get the desired info:

```
3266 bin/rails server -dp 3000
3383 bin/rails s -dp 4000
```

But when I put it into an alias in ~/.bash_aliases (which is included in ~/.bashrc)

```
alias findrails_pid="ps aux | grep rails | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2, $12, $13, $14, $15}'"
```

and source:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

It breaks...I get:

```
vagrant@Railsvr:~$ findrails_pid 
awk: {print , 2, 3, 4, 5}
awk:        ^ syntax error
```

It is as though the $n, which represent columns from the ps aux command, are being ripped out for some reason. This is the first alias I have tried to create - am I missing something?

Not sure if this matters - system is an ubuntu precise32 guest box hosted by libvirt-kvm on a Debian 8.1 host.

Comment: I typically put fancy stuff into shell functions, not aliases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function would probably be better, yes, but in this case the problem probably is because you are using double quotes around it.  The $ variables get expanded before the assignment to the alias.  You can use a single quote on the outside instead, or, because you already have single quotes, escape the $ with \:

```
alias findrails_pid="ps aux | grep rails | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2, \$12, \$13, \$14, \$15}'"
```

Comment: Ah - because single quotes interpret contents literally?

Comment: Yes, and double quotes allow variables to be interpolated into the string.

Comment: That works nicely. Thank you for the assist.